# pandas - update value in dataframe from split element of another df element

Tags: python, pandas

Python newb learning Pandas, so this is likely not the correct way to approach this.

In dataframe `df`, have columns `testID` and `proj`.

`testID` is an `int` (eg '23'), and `proj` is an underscore_separated_name with 3 parts (e.g. `bob_xp_sam`). I wish to modify all `testID` values to become, for eg., `xp-23` (by capturing the `"xp"` from `proj` and concatinating it to each existing `testID` value.)

This is where I am at, but it doesn't fly:

```
df['testID'] = df['proj'].str.split('_')[1] +'-'+ df['testID']
```

I have tried variations, such as:

```
df['proj'].split('_')[1]
 > AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'

df['proj'].str.split('_')[1]
> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Pretty sure my approach is wrong - a little direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need another `str` accessor before `[1]` to access individual element in the list type column (returned by `split`):

```
df['proj'].str.split('_').str[1]
#                         ^^^
```